# Discord.py bot has issue with json

Tags: python, discord.py

So, I have a bot, I want it to save data to json file, I get error when running:

```
Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 307, in _run_event
    yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/zorin/Desktop/den.py", line 14, in on_ready
    amounts = json.load(f)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 299, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Is there a special way I should be doing this? Json file is a empty amounts.json.

Code:

```
from discord.ext import commands
import json
import discord

bot = commands.Bot('!')

amounts = {}

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    global amounts
    try:
        with open('amounts.json') as f:
            amounts = json.load(f)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Could not load amounts.json")
        amounts = {}

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def balance(ctx):
    id = ctx.message.author.id
    if id in amounts:
        await bot.say("You have {} in the bank".format(amounts[ctx.message.author.id]))
    else:
        await bot.say("You do not have an account")

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def register(ctx):
    id = ctx.message.author.id
    if id not in amounts:
        amounts[id] = 100
        await bot.say("You are now registered")
    else:
        await bot.say("You already have an account")

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def transfer(ctx, amount: int, other: discord.Member):
    primary_id = ctx.message.author.id
    other_id = other.id
    if primary_id not in amounts:
        await bot.say("You do not have an account")
    elif other_id not in amounts:
        await bot.say("The other party does not have an account")
    elif amounts[primary_id] < amount:
        await bot.say("You cannot afford this transaction")
    else:
        amounts[primary_id] -= amount
        amounts[other_id] += amount
        await bot.say("Transaction complete")

@bot.command()
async def save():
    with open('amounts.json', 'w+') as f:
        json.dump(amounts, f)

bot.run("secret token")
```

Comment: Let's see the JSON.

Comment: @JacobIRR The abouts.json is empty, nothing in it. Pure blank. What should I have in it?

Comment: well, seeing how it's JSON, it needs to have JSON inside it.

Comment: What do you mean? Can you put what I should have in it?

Comment: You could start with: `{"foo":"bar"}`

Comment: An empty file is invalid JSON.  Just have `{}` inside the file.